# Testing vuejs prop default, that is a function in jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Following is my vuejs code:

```
    export default {
name: 'LineChart',
extends: Line,
props: {
   labelFunction: {
    type: Function,
    required: false,
    default: (label) => label,
  },
}
computed: {
    options() {
        return {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [
                {
                    ticks: {
                    callback: this.labelFunction,
                    },
                }],
            }
        }
    }
},
}
```

I want to write the test case for `labelFunction`. I want to cover it's default value.

How can I do that?

Comment: labelFunction: {...default: (label) => (label)}; expect(wrapper.vm.labelFunction.default("test")).toBe("test")

Comment: @MohammadRezaAbbasi .. it Is giving an error as: default is not a function

Comment: in test `expect(wrapper.vm.labelFunction("test")).toBe("test")`

Comment: @MohammadRezaAbbasi .. It failed ...Expected: "test"
    Received: "NaN"

Comment: change props in code: `labelFunction: { type: Function, required: false, default: (label) => (label) }` => add () to labale

Comment: @MohammadRezaAbbasi ..could you please write it in Answer section? I am not getting...

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm having the same issue